# Estimate value of dependent variable such that P(Y>y|X=x) = p

Tags: logistic, quantiles

I want to model a dependent variable Y on an independent variable X (and possibly some covariates as well). In my situation, it is safe to assume that the relationship is monotonically increasing. Once the model is built, I will have new observations of X.  For each, I want to estimate the value of Y such that the new case has probability p of exceeding the estimate.

This is sort of like a reverse of logistic regression.  Instead of fixing the cutoff criterion for Y to be considered a success and estimating for each case the probability of success given the observed value of X, I want to fix the probability of success and estimate for each case the cutoff criterion for Y given the observed value of X.

I know that, if I have a bivariate normal distribution, the distribution of a prediction is a location-scaled t distribution whose parameters can be derived from the regression model and the observed X value, and so I can use the quantile function of that distribution to find the desired value of Y.  However, if there exists a statistical technique designed for the current purpose, and which makes fewer assumptions (or is more robust to violations of assumptions) than linear regression, I'd prefer to use that instead.

Comment: Interesting question! I think you might want to break up your first paragraph, it is a bit imposing at its current length. (You can also remove the "thanks in advance" at the end - we try to keep questions very much "to the point" here; it may feel a bit rude at first that we don't do a lot of pleasantries in the text of a question but the idea is to make it easier for readers to extract the information they need.)

Comment: Some assumptions are necessary for there to exist solutions and for them to be unique.  What can you tell us about the conditional distribution of $Y$?

Comment: whuber: The conditional distribution of Y|X is (probably) uni-modal, and (probably) asymmetric.  As X increases, the mean of Y|X will also increase, and any quantile of Y|X will also (probably) increase.  The particular Y variable I am working with happens to be bounded [0,100], but could be transformed if necessary.

Comment: Silverfish: Thanks for the tip.  Hopefully it's a bit more readable now.

Comment: Your assumptions might need to be tweaked a little: you want the specified quantile to be a monotonic function of $X$ no matter what the fitted coefficients may be (provided only that the slope is positive).  This is assured for homoscedastic mean-zero responses of a fixed shape (such as Gaussian), but could be more problematic in the situation you posit.

Comment: whuber: My assumption (based on knowledge of the situation generating the data) is that the the specified quantile will be a non-decreasing function of X.  It's not that I want it to be; it's that I am fairly certain that it is.  Is that what you meant?